# Why is my GeoLocation distance value so minutely off-set from the given value for my programming task?

Tags: java, class, arraylist, methods, geolocation

I'm currently working through my CodeHS tasks. I've finished the task in hand and it works fine, but the value calculated for the 'GeoLocation' (e.g, the distance in miles between two places) is off by around 1.10-2.80 every single time, so the program won't allow me to continue.

I've got screenshots of my method to calculate the distance, my method to sum all the distances, and my result. I'll also provide screenshots of the entire code as well in link form at the bottom.

I'm really not sure if this is a bug, or if I'm doing something wrong, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks all! :)

[This is my method to calculate the distance between two places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWjLF.png)

[This is my method to calculate the sum of all of the distances, for each 'stop' on the road trip (value in the ArrayList)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSrJH.png)

[This is the output the task wants, and my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsT1M.png)

And just for clarity if anyone wants it, here is screenshots of my 3 entire classes and the program task.

[GeoLocation Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peHGc.png)

[RoadTrip Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/679ri.png)

[RoadTripTester, or 'Main' class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gllBx.png)

[Full task summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3Ndp.png)

**Again, thank you everyone who even looks at this - I appreciate it.**

Comment: Put the code directly in the question and not as pictures. Do you expect us to rewrite everything from those pictures?

Answer (score -1):

In your `getTripLength()` method, you must change `tripLength` to a `double` not an `int`